# Pre-fill tags when linking directly to "Ask Question"

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

How can I create a link, inside a HTML page, that would link to the "Ask Question" page, with pre-populated tags?

For example, something like this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=tag1|tag2|tag3">...</a>
```

Is this even possible?

This would make it a lot easier for me to forward people to ask questions on Stack Overflow about a specific topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there is nothing stopping you doing this - you need to use spaces to separate the tags:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=tag1%20tag2%20tag3">...</a>
```

I'd recommend you think hard about what message you are giving the people following that link.

For example if these people paid you for a service or some software, then dumping them on a public site (especially one that appears to be getting less tolerant of new users asking poor questions) isn't what you should be doing. Were I one of your customers I would feel particularly aggrieved if that happened to me.

Even if you're not offering a paid service sending people to the question page is not the best introduction to Stack Overflow. They'll have no idea of what the site culture is like, the chances of them asking a duplicate question are higher than if they'd come across the site normally.

The history of such links has not been an auspicious one. People have set one up and then left those following it to their own devices, offering no guidance on how to ask a good question, and often not warning people that it was a link to another site.

On balance this isn't a good idea, but if you really insist on doing this then you **must** be active in those tags and try to provide answers or at the very least guidance to your customers. Ideally you'd also have a reputation of 2,000+ so you could edit any less than stellar questions into shape before they down-voted.

Comment: this is pretty useful in combination with a private Stackoverflow for Teams to funnel questions from a slack channel to a specific tag